# Converting column values to column names in pandas with other column values as new column values

Tags: python, pandas

I know the title sounds confusing. But let me explain with an example. I have date vise data of covid cases in states of India.

The data is of the below form

[image]

I want it to be like

[image: Final]

Each date can have new state names based of if those states got new cases. So for each date the data can have varied number of states name as per first image.

Comment: you need to use pandas `pivot_table` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: I didn't know about pivot feature. Let me check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pandas.DataFrame.pivot`:

```
df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Name', values='Numbers')
```

Comment: How can I sort these values based on the values after pivoting

Comment: like this: df.sort_values(by=1, ascending=False, axis=1)

Comment: 1694         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 1

Comment: Did you try to rename the rowname? df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False, axis=1)

Comment: No I used as it is....